# Is it possible to return a 304 Not Modified with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, http-headers, http-status-code-304

If a user has a file cached in their browser and they send a http request with an `If-Modified-Since` header, is there a way to automatically serve them a `304 Not Modified` response using .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An indirect solution:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:if-modified-since} .
RewriteRule . /not_modified.php [L]
```

not_modified.php:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 304 Not Modified');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following links:

1. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/caching.html
2. http://www.chicagostyleseo.com/2010/04/googles-need-for-speed-use-cache-and-htaccess-to-speed-up-your-site/
3. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-last-modified.html

Notice, that from the above link:

> If you remove the Last-Modified and ETag header, you will totally
>   eliminate If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests and their 304
>   Not Modified Responses, so a file will stay cached without checking
>   for updates until the Expires header indicates new content is
>   available!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that simply clicking the 'refresh' button on the browser will trigger an If-modified-since request regardless of the expires header.

Comment: @skibulk - Yes, I think this part is browser specific. I also think it's mentioned in the aboved links.

Comment: I thought expires took precedence. So the browser would keep using the cached version until it expired, and then after that use a IfModifiedSince, to prevent double download if it still hasn't changed